# How to remove bullet points from Woocommerce products widget

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

has anyone had the same issue with me? I am adding the recently viewed products widget via the **woocommerce** plugin but **bullet points** appear next to the product title. I have tried to add several codes in my custom css but i have not found the solution. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: here you can see a print screen of the problem: http://imgur.com/sgt9cGH    Notice the bullet points on the left

Comment: What CSS have you used? How are you loading your CSS? (Because keep in mind that WooCommerce's stylesheet is typically loaded *after* your theme's style.css.) However, I'm fairly certain that's coming from your theme since I've never seen that in WC. Do you have a link?

Comment: @InspiredLogic Please at least share your website link.

Comment: i don't have a link since i work at localhost, i am using custom css plugin for the stylesheet. I have found every possible class from the browser's page source and I have used the following code:    list-style-type: none;  
It still doesn't work

Comment: Notice the bullet point is IN FRONT OF the number,seems it is executed by something else, or the bullet points belong to the image ?

Comment: this is the code of the plugin:


if ( $r->have_posts() ) {

   $this->widget_start( $args, $instance );

   echo '<ul class="product_list_widget">';

   while ( $r->have_posts() ) {
    $r->the_post();
    wc_get_template( 'content-widget-product.php' );
   }

   echo '</ul>';

   $this->widget_end( $args );
  }

Answer (score 0):

ok i added this css code to leave some space between the bullet point and the product title since i haven't found a solution to remove the bullet points completely.

```
.product-title{
padding-left:10px !important;

}
```

Comment: this doesn't fully answer the question, please be more descriptive with your answer, or leave additional details such as this in a comment

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Add the following to your custom CSS

```
.woocommerce #content div.product ul li.description_tab {
    display: none !important;
}
.woocommerce ul.products {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
.content ul {
list-style: disc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I targeted all the `li` elements on the offending page with some inline css

```
<style>
 li {
  list-style-type: none;
 }
</style>
```